# Table with binding to data

Tags: wpf

I want to build table from a data-model via DataBinding and not found how to do it. I have a data like this:

```
1.type CustomObj with slots:
- id
- a
- b    
2. variable Content of type <List of CustomObj>

How to make a table like as below:

+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|Identifier          |a slot              |b slot              |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|'id from first eleme|'a from first elemen|b from first elemen |
|t                   |t                   |t                   |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|...                 |...                 |...                 |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I read about FlowDocument but not found how to build flow document from List via DataBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, use a [DataGrid](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

Create a `ObservableCollection<CustomObj>` and bind the DataGrids `ItemsSource` to this OC.

Your DataGrid could look like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CustomObjList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Identifier" Binding="{Binding id}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="a Slot" Binding="{Binding a}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="b Slot" Binding="{Binding b}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```